# Could not autowire. No beans of 'InstructionRepository' type found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javabeans, autowired

Trying to create a bean in SpringBoot application, but getting the following error "Could not autowire. No beans of 'InstructionRepository' type found."

InstructionRepository is annotated with @Repository annotation in the jar and is an Interface extending a Spring Data Interface

ScheduleProcessor is a method

When I Try adding the @ComponentScan annotation by passing the base package value, the error goes away BUT, when I boot up the application get the following error

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.xxx.resync.config.AppConfig required a bean of type 'com.xxx.repo.InstructionRepository' that could not be found. Action: Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xxx.repo.InstructionRepository' in your configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxx.repo"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${pssHttp.connectTimeout:3000}")
    private int connectTimeout;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        factory.setReadTimeout(connectTimeout);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ScheduleUpdater getScheduleUpdater() {
        return new ScheduleUpdater(true);
    }

    @Bean
    public ScheduleProcessor scheduleProcessor(InstructionRepository instructionRepository, ScheduleUpdater scheduleUpdater) {
        return new ScheduleProcessor(instructionRepository, scheduleUpdater);
    }
}
```

InstructionRepository

```
@Repository
public interface InstructionRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Instruction, String> {

}
```

How can we fix the error and be able to boot up the Spring boot application?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  `@EnableCouchbaseRepositories` to enable repo building eg to `AppConfig`.

Comment: Unable to find a maven dependency for EnableJpaRepositories, how do we add this dependency

Comment: its part of spring data https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html

Comment: You have to use `@EnableCouchbaseRepositories`

Comment: Added in the AppConfig, but still having the same error.

Comment: add like this `@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.xxx.repo"})`